# Ionic Capacitor : Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I’m having this issue because of the minimum target SDK 31 update for the Play Store

I’ve had the App working well, I changed the TargetSDK in the gradle variables file and I’m getting this error :

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Here’s the List of My Plugins :
(npx cap ls)

```
   @capacitor-community/admob@3.2.0
   @capacitor/app@1.1.1
   @capacitor/haptics@1.1.4
   @capacitor/keyboard@1.2.2
   @capacitor/push-notifications@1.0.9
   @capacitor/splash-screen@1.2.2
   @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.8
   @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth@3.1.4
[info] Listing plugins for web is not possible.
```

I’ve read That I need to upgrade some plugins but i don’t know which ones

Can you please help me

Answer (score 2):

To properly support SDK 31/32 you have to upgrade to capacitor 4.

Run `npm i @capacitor/cli@latest`. And then run `npx cap migrate`. That will update all capacitor dependencies and plugins to version 4 and make required changes to your native projects.